# Which database for storing file paths?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, database-design

I'm building an application with the instant messaging functionality.
The application will allow the users to send files/images as well as normal text messages.

I decided to take the approach with storing the files on the filesystem and write only the file paths to the database. There will be no updates to the files (only insertions and deletions).

Which database would be the best for storing a large amount of file paths, that would be easy to query for a certain user files?

Comment: how large amount of files? 1G or 1M or 100K? what platform?What database?...

Comment: With MySQL. Table design depends on how many files/images per message/user. It would take at least four tables: Users; Messages; Files; Messages_Files. That last table would link Files to Messages. Or you could eliminate that last table if each file row has a foreign key to it's message and another to it's user.

Comment: I'm in the planning phase right now. I expect the single files to be usually over 10 MB. The total amount of files wouldn't probably exceed 100k at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with MongoDB. My experience is that a document based approach using a single Messages collection would be best. Each message document then contains all of the file paths. This eliminates joins and better supports potential future functional requirements changes.

MongoDB also provides great ways to deal with old messages such as TTL indexes.

Comment: Would I be able to tackle the problem of deleting a file from filesystem and the filepath entry from the database as one atomic operation? Does MongoDB let me use transaction-like approach?

Comment: For that case, I would strongly consider storing the files in GridFS (within Mongo) then using transactions. The delete could then be performed as a single action.